# Numpy->Cython conversion: Compile error:Cannot convert 'npy_intp *' to Python object

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-2.7, cython

I have the following code that is to be propperly converted to cython:

```
from numpy import *

## returns winning players or [] if undecided. 
def score(board):
    scores = []
    checked = zeros(board.shape)
    for i in xrange(len(board)):
        for j in xrange(len(board)):
            if checked[i,j] == 0 and board[i,j] !=0:
                ... do stuf
```

my attempt at conversion to cython:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)

## returns winning players or [] if undecided. 
def score(np.ndarray[int, ndim=2] board):
    scores = []
    cdef np.ndarray[int, ndim = 2 ] checked
    checked = np.zeros(board.shape)
    for i in xrange(len(board)):
        for j in xrange(len(board)):
            if checked[i,j] == 0 and board[i,j] !=0:
                ... do stuf
```

But when I compile I get :

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning newgox.pyx to newgox.c


## returns winning players or [] if undecided. 
def score(np.ndarray[int, ndim=2] board):
    scores = []
    cdef np.ndarray[int, ndim = 2 ] checked
    checked = np.zeros(board.shape)
                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

newgox.pyx:58:28: Cannot convert 'npy_intp *' to Python object 
building 'newgox' extension
```

Also, I'm not sure this is the right way to work with lists in cython:

```
scores = []
if some_stuff_is_true:
    scores.append(some_integer)
```

EDIT:

Thanks, the code now compiles but when I run it I get the error:

```
File "newgox.pyx", line 63, in newgox.score (newgox.c:1710)
    def score(np.ndarray[np.int, ndim=2] board):
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int object' but got 'long'
```

I tied these two options:

```
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t
DTYPE = np.int
```

and then continue to:

```
board = zeros((5,5), dtype = DTYPE)
def score(np.ndarray[DTYPE, ndim=2] board):
```

or just in both declarations:

```
    ...  np.int ...
```

This results in the same error, but with signature:

```
 ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got 'long'
```

---

Thanks bellamyj, but your suggested code won't compile,

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning newgox.pyx to newgox.c
building 'newgox' extension
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c newgox.c -o   build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/newgox.o

newgox.c:238:31: error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
newgox.c:239:31: error: numpy/ufuncobject.h: No such file or directory
newgox.c:356: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__pyx_t_5numpy_int8_t’
newgox.c:365: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__pyx_t_5numpy_int16_t’
newgox.c:374: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__pyx_t_5numpy_int32_t’
```

And it continues to enumerate all other types as well.

Then is tells me this:

```
newgox.c:978: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
newgox.c:979: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
newgox.c:980: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
newgox.c:983: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyArrayObject’
newgox.c:984: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyArrayObject’
newgox.c:985: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
newgox.c:987: error: ‘__pyx_t_5numpy_int32_t’ undeclared here (not in a function)
newgox.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6newgox_7score’:
newgox.c:1638: error: ‘PyArrayObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
newgox.c:1638: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
newgox.c:1638: error: for each function it appears in.)
newgox.c:1638: error: ‘__pyx_v_checked’ undeclared (first use in this function)
newgox.c:1659: error: ‘__pyx_t_5’ undeclared (first use in this function)
newgox.c:1721: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:1723: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:1747: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:1766: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:1813: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:1846: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:1846: error: too many arguments to function ‘__pyx_f_6newgox_check_life’
newgox.c:2009: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:2009: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
newgox.c:2012: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:2032: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c: At top level:
newgox.c:2088: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyArrayObject’
newgox.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_6newgox_check_life’:
newgox.c:2124: error: ‘__pyx_v_board’ undeclared (first use in this function)
newgox.c:2160: error: ‘PyArrayObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
newgox.c:2160: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:2160: error: too many arguments to function ‘__pyx_f_6newgox_liberty’
newgox.c:2420: error: too many arguments to function ‘__pyx_f_6newgox_check_life’
newgox.c: At top level:
newgox.c:2583: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyArrayObject’
newgox.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_6newgox_liberty’:
newgox.c:2610: error: ‘__pyx_v_board’ undeclared (first use in this function)
newgox.c: At top level:
newgox.c:2859: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
newgox.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_5numpy_7ndarray___getbuffer__’:
newgox.c:2999: error: ‘PyArray_Descr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
newgox.c:2999: error: ‘__pyx_v_descr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
newgox.c:3062: error: ‘PyArrayObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
newgox.c:3062: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:3071: error: ‘npy_intp’ undeclared (first use in this function)
newgox.c:3114: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:3114: error: ‘NPY_C_CONTIGUOUS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
newgox.c:3154: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:3154: error: ‘NPY_F_CONTIGUOUS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
newgox.c:3184: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:3184: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
newgox.c:3240: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:3240: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
newgox.c:3249: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:3249: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
newgox.c:3262: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:3271: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
newgox.c:3291: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
```

And some more.

Notice it says :

```
newgox.c:2160: error: too many arguments to function ‘__pyx_f_6newgox_liberty’
newgox.c:2420: error: too many arguments to function ‘__pyx_f_6newgox_check_life’
```

But my call from score/1 to check_life is:

```
life, newly_checked = check_life(i,j,board,[])
```

And it is received like this:

```
# helper functions of score/1
cdef check_life(int i, int j, np.ndarray[int, ndim=2] board, checked):
    ...
    return life, checked
```

Finally, what kind of data type is the "i4" that you use?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think tuple unpacking works in Cython like it does in Python.  You have to specify the size of `checked` using `(board.shape[0], board.shape[1])`.

You also need to specify the datatype of `checked`.  By default `np.zeros` returns a `float64`.  You need to change that to an `int32` to be compatible with the declared type.

Here's a modified version that should run.

```
def score(np.ndarray[int, ndim=2] board):

    cdef np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim = 2] checked
    checked = np.zeros((board.shape[0], board.shape[1]), dtype='i4')

    for i in xrange(len(board)):
        for j in xrange(len(board)):
            if checked[i,j] == 0 and board[i,j] !=0:
                ... do stuff
```

To answer the second part of your question - yes you can append to lists within Cython functions.  However, as I understand it this involves Python function calls, so it won't be any faster than the same operations within Python.

**Update 1:**

I believe those errors are because the compiler can't find the NumPy header files.  Update your setup.py to include the path to those files.  The path should be output by the `np.get_include()` function.

```
import numpy as np
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
      cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules = [
              Extension("new_gox",
                        ["new_gox.pyx"],
                        include_dirs=[np.get_include()])
                    ]
     )
```

The dtype `i4` is a 32 bit integer.  It's equivalent to `np.int32`.

I'm not sure what's going on with the 'too many arguments' errors.  If you're calling that function from within Python, it needs to be declared as either `def` or `cpdef`.  Functions declared with `cdef` can only be called from Cython.  This is described [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#python-functions-vs-c-functions) in the Cython docs.

Answer (score 0):

np.intp is same as (void *)

define its type like this:

```
ctypedef np.npy_intp SIZE_t              # Type for indices and counters
```

source:

[NPY_INTP == The enumeration value for a signed integer type which is the same size as a (void *) pointer. This is the type used by all arrays of indices.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.dtype.html)

So for example in cython...

Struct in header file.h file:

```
struct Cudamat_Struct1 {
    float * dataHost;
    float * dataDevice;
    int onDevice;
    int onHost;
    (void *) shape;
    int size;
    int isTrans; // 0 or 1
    int ownsData;

};
```

In cython file.pxd file:

```
cdef extern from "file.h":
    cdef cppclass c_Cudamat_Struct "Cudamat_Struct":
        float *dataHost
        float *dataDevice
        bint onDevice
        bint onHost
        SIZE_t * shape
        int size
        bint isTrans
        bint ownsData
```

Finally in cython function:

```
cdef pycublas_thrust_2d():
    cdef c_Cudamat_Struct1* mat = new c_Cudamat_Struct1()

    cdef int N = 10

    cdef np.ndarray[ndim=2, dtype=F32t] arrHost = np.ones((1,10),dtype=F32)

    cdef int size = 10

    cdef F32t[:,:] arrHost_ = arrHost

    cdef F32t * arrHostPtr = &arrHost[0,0]

    mat.dataHost = arrHostPtr
    mat.shape = arrHost.shape
    mat.size = size
```