# Cython: Why do NumPy arrays need to be type-cast to object?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have seen something like this a few times in the [Pandas source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/737b3297e2d03492acbbe74eca5dfc2eb62cf207/pandas/_libs/algos.pyx#L242):

```
def nancorr(ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] mat, bint cov=0, minp=None):
    # ...
    N, K = (<object> mat).shape
```

This implies that a NumPy `ndarray` called `mat` is [type-casted](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#type-casting) to a Python object.<sup>*</sup>

Upon further inspection, it seems like this is used because a compile error arises if it isn't.  My question is: **why is this type-cast required in the first place**?

Here are a few examples.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9456949/7954504) answer suggest simply that tuple packing doesn't work in Cython like it does in Python---but it doesn't seem to be a tuple unpacking issue.  (It is a fine answer regardless, and I don't mean to pick on it.)

Take the following script, `shape.pyx`.  It will fail at compile time with "Cannot convert 'npy_intp *' to Python object."

```
from cython cimport Py_ssize_t
import numpy as np
from numpy cimport ndarray, float64_t
cimport numpy as cnp
cnp.import_array()

def test_castobj(ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] arr):

    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t b1, b2

    # Tuple unpacking - this will fail at compile
    b1, b2 = arr.shape
    return b1, b2
```

But again, the issue does not seem to be tuple *unpacking*, per se.  This will fail with the same error.

```
def test_castobj(ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] arr):

    cdef:
        # Py_ssize_t b1, b2
        ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] zeros

    zeros = np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype=np.float64)
    return zeros
```

Seemingly, no tuple unpacking is happening here.  A tuple is the first arg to `np.zeros`.

```
def test_castobj(ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] arr):
    """This works"""
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t b1, b2
        ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] zeros

    b1, b2 = (<object> arr).shape
    zeros = np.zeros((<object> arr).shape, dtype=np.float64)
    return b1, b2, zeros
```

This also works (perhaps the most confusing of all):

```
def test_castobj(object[float64_t, ndim=2] arr):
    cdef:
        tuple shape = arr.shape
        ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] zeros
    zeros = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.float64)
    return zeros
```

Example:

```
>>> from shape import test_castobj
>>> arr = np.arange(6, dtype=np.float64).reshape(2, 3)

>>> test_castobj(arr)
(2, 3, array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]))
```

<sub>*Perhaps it has something to do with `arr` being a memoryview?  But that's a shot in the dark.</sub>

---

Another example is in the Cython [docs](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#quickstart):

```
cpdef int sum3d(int[:, :, :] arr) nogil:
    cdef size_t i, j, k
    cdef int total = 0
    I = arr.shape[0]
    J = arr.shape[1]
    K = arr.shape[2]
```

In this case, simply indexing `arr.shape[i]` prevents the error, which I find strange.

This also works:

```
def test_castobj(object[float64_t, ndim=2] arr):
    cdef ndarray[float64_t, ndim=2] zeros
    zeros = np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype=np.float64)
    return zeros
```

Comment: I don't know Cpython, but at least in `c`, if `arr.shape` returns a pointer (it seems to), you (and numpy) have no method to know it's dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it has nothing to do with the tuple-unpacking under Cython.

The reason is, that `cnp.ndarray` isn't an usual numpy-array (that means a numpy-array with interface known from python), but a [Cython wrapper](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/adeef15221b37760e07b3cc8ac50f4b2d534f275/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd#L199) of the numpy's C-implementation for [`PyArrayObject`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L719) (which is known as `np.array` in Python):

```
ctypedef class numpy.ndarray [object PyArrayObject]:
    cdef __cythonbufferdefaults__ = {"mode": "strided"}

    cdef:
        # Only taking a few of the most commonly used and stable fields.
        # One should use PyArray_* macros instead to access the C fields.
        char *data
        int ndim "nd"
        npy_intp *shape "dimensions"
        npy_intp *strides
        dtype descr
        PyObject* base
```

`shape` maps in reality to [`dimensions`-field](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L676) (`npy_intp *shape "dimensions"` instead of simply `npy_intp *dimensions`) of the underlying C-stuct. It is a trick, so one can write

```
mat.shape[0]
```

and it has the looks (and to some degree the feel) as if numpy's python-property `shape` is called. But in reality a shortcut directly to the underlying C-stuct is taken.

Btw calling python-`shape` is quite costly: a tuple must be created and filled with values from `dimensions`, then the 0-th element is accessed.  On the other hand, Cython's way of doing it is much cheaper - just access the right element.

However, if you yet want access the python-property of the array, you have to cast it to a normal python-object (i.e. forget that this is a `ndarray`) and then `shape` is resolved to the tuple-property call via the usual Python-mechanism.

So basically, even if this is convenient, you don't want to access the dimensions of the numpy array in a tight loop the way it is done in the pandas-code, instead you would do the more verbose variant for performance:

```
...
N=mat.shape[0]
K=mat.shape[1]
...
```

---

Why you can write `object[cnp.float64_t]` or similar in the function signature strikes me as strange - the parameter is then obviously interpreted as a simple object. Maybe this is just a bug.